# Django Static Image Not Serving

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have a simple django app I am trying to build and I am trying to display an image on the front page. When i load the front page the image is not there. But when i go directly to the image url it shows just fine. I have been following the django documentation and I can not seem to solve this issue.

My site structure is like this

```
Main Dir
    -app
    -website
    -static
        --images
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/path/to/static/root/directory/',)
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<div class="parallax"><img src="{% static 'images/frontbannar.jpg' %}" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
```

I have also run this command and it did not work.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Settings don't look fine: see `DIRNAME` vs `BASE_DIR`. Templates looks ok. `it did not work` - an error or what?

Comment: also show your urls.py